# pandas astype python bool instead of numpy.bool_

Tags: python, pandas, python-2.7, numpy

I need to convert a pandas dataframe to a JSON object.

However

```
json.dumps(df.to_dict(orient='records'))
```

fails as the boolean columns are not JSON serializable since they are of type `numpy.bool_`. Now I've tried `df['boolCol'] = df['boolCol'].astype(bool)` but that still leaves the type of the fields as `numpy.bool_` rather than the pyhton bool which serializes to JSON no problem.

Any suggestions on how to convert the columns without looping through every record and converting it?

Thanks

EDIT:

This is part of a whole sanitization of dataframes of varying content so they can be used as the JSON payload for an API. Hence we currently have something like this:

```
for cols in df.columns:
    if type(df[cols][0]) == pd._libs.tslibs.timestamps.Timestamp:
        df[cols] = df[cols].astype(str)
    elif type(df[cols]) == numpy.bool_:
        df[cols] = df[cols].astype(bool) #still numnpy bool afterwards!
```

Comment: a shot in the dark, but are you sure that `df` is a pandas data frame and not a numpy array?

Comment: `>>> type(df)`
`<class 'pandas.core.frame.DataFrame'>` yep :)

Comment: so far `json.loads(df.to_json(orient='records'))` will work but seems like a poor solution

Comment: Don't you consider using Python 3? In Python 3, the type of that field will be `<class 'bool'>` and `json.dumps` can be executed successfully.

Answer (score 1):

Just tested it out, and the problem seems to be caused by the orient='records' parameter. Seems you have to set it to a option (e.g. list) and convert the results to your preferred format.

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
column_name = 'bool_col'

bool_df = pd.DataFrame(np.array([True, False, True]), columns=[column_name])

list_repres = bool_df.to_dict('list')
record_repres = [{column_name: values} for values in list_repres[column_name]]

json.dumps(record_repres)
```

Comment: sorry should have mentioned this is not the only column in the dataframe. There are a number of columns and I just need the various columns with non-serializable datatypes. something along the lines of looping through the df columns, and change the type if an entry in that column is not serializable. I'll update the question above.

Answer (score 1):

You need to use `.astype` and set its field `dtype` to object

See example below:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({
   "time": ['0hr', '128hr', '72hr', '48hr', '96hr'],
   "value": [10, 20, 30, 40, None]
})
df['revoked'] = False
df.revoked = df.revoked.astype(bool)
print 'setting astype as bool:', type(df.iloc[0]['revoked'])


df.revoked = df.revoked.astype(object)
print 'setting astype as object:', type(df.iloc[0]['revoked'])


>>> setting astype as bool: <type 'numpy.bool_'>
>>> setting astype as object: <type 'bool'>
```